# check if a list of object is blank in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

lets say I have this

```
@objects = SampleObject.all
```

then I want to check if @objects is blank, I could the ff:

```
unless @objects.blank?
 @objects.each do |object|
 end
else
..
end
```

however, doing so will trigger rails to execute a SELECT count(*) query

so instead, I could do something like

```
unless @objects.length > 0
```

is there a way to override the `.blank?` given a particular class?

say

```
def self.empty?  
  self.length > 0 ?  false : true <br>
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`ActiveRecord::Relation#any?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-any-3F) method:

```
if @objects.any?
  # ...
end
```

which is (in this case) negation of [`ActiveRecord::Relation#empty?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-empty-3F) method:

```
unless @objects.empty?
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for that method however, when I tested it, the mini-profiler is telling me that rails fired a SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "objects" via the .any? method

Comment: @rav ok, so then what's your goal? How do you want it to be (since in my opinion, generating `select count(*) ...` query is the best way to check if there are any records)?

Comment: Hi, for example I already queried something say @objects = SampleObject.all. I just want to check if the list is blank or not without another query to the DB.

Comment: @rav In Rails console, I can see, *sql* query is running when you do `@objects = SampleObject.all`, but no query when `@objects.any?`..

Comment: @ArupRakshit so try `SampleObject.all.any?` and you'll see the difference between console and "real life". :)

Comment: @MarekLipka yes, that would do,, but not `@objects.any?` ... I saw it.

Comment: @rav the same answer is for you. `@objects = SampleObject.all` doesn't fire SQL query immediately. `ActiveRecord::Relation` objects are evaluated lazily, only when they're needed. So this piece of code in "regular" application does two things: First, it fires `count` SQL query to check if there are records. If there are, it fires regular `select` to fetch them. Which is perfectly normal and correct.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up. I have a better understanding now. Thanks

Comment: @MarekLipka I think the OP's problem is that 2 queries are executed, one for `@objects.any?` and another one for `@objects.each`

Answer (score 1):

blank? uses empty?, since `blank?` source code:

```
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb, line 13
  def blank?
    respond_to?(:empty?) ? empty? : !self
  end
```

Now the docs about **[empty?](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy/empty??q=empty)** says:

> Returns true if the collection is empty.
>
> If the collection has been
>   loaded or the :counter_sql option is provided, it is equivalent to
>   collection.size.zero?.
>
> If the collection has not been loaded, it is
>   equivalent to collection.exists?.
>
> If the collection has not already
>   been loaded and you are going to fetch the records anyway it is better
>   to check collection.length.zero?

So, it really depends weather the collection is loaded or not? 
Both `empty?` & `any?` use `SELEC COUNT(*)` if the collection isn't loaded ([reference](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb#L262-272)), i think in your case `SampleObject.all` will be lazy loaded as @Marek said, thus the `COUNT` calls.

For your case i don't think you can avoid the `COUNT` call since you want to fetch all records and eager loading all records just to avoid a second call to db just feels pointless (solving one performance issue by causing bigger one), however if its a subset collection, i believe there will be no second `COUNT` call.

Answer (score 0):

`SampleObject.all` gives [`ActiveRecord::Relation`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) object, you can use [`blank?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-blank-3F) also.

> **blank?** - Returns true if relation is blank

Thus you can write as

```
unless @objects.blank?
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call [`ActiveRecord::Relation#to_a`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-to_a) to execute the query immediately:

```
@objects = SampleObject.all.to_a  # runs the query, returns an array

if @objects.any?                  # no query, this is Enumerable#any?
  # ...
end
```